# Task.Run on web farm not running correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a call to write to a log file whenever the API is called. This works flawlessly on single machine but as soon as it is moved to a web farm, then nothing gets written. No errors are raised either.

Here is how things are arranged

1. Call to API

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public model.Returns Get([FromUri] model.Requests requests)
   ```
2. With this function, Get, is a call to write to the log file like so

   ```
   //record request
   Task.Run(() => writers.WriteApiLogAsync(requests));
   ```
3. Within the WriteApiLogAsync is this

   ```
       logs.Add(new model.Log()
       {
           Type = requests.t,
           When = DateTime.Now,
           PhoneId = requests.p,
           Location = requests.l,
           Phone = requests.ph,
           PhoneType = requests.pt
       });

       //file is locked, attempt write on next round but stack log entries
       if (logLocker.IsWriterLockHeld) return;

       try
       {
           var result = await writeLogs(logs);
           if(result) logLocker.ReleaseWriterLock();
       }
       catch (OutOfMemoryException ex)
       {
           WriteErrorAsnc(ex.Message, ex.ToString(), "WriteApiLogAsync_OutOfMemoryException");
           logs.Clear();
           logLocker.ReleaseWriterLock();
       }
       catch (IOException ex)
       {
           WriteErrorAsnc(ex.Message, ex.ToString(), "WriteApiLogAsync_IOException");
           logs.Clear();
           logLocker.ReleaseWriterLock();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           WriteErrorAsnc(ex.Message, ex.ToString(), "WriteApiLogAsync_Exception");
           logs.Clear();
           logLocker.ReleaseWriterLock();
       }
       finally
       {
           if (logs.Count > 1000)
           {
               logs.Clear();
               logLocker.ReleaseWriterLock();
           }
       }
   ```

logs is set as

```
private static List<model.Log> logs = new List<model.Log>();
```

I didn't specify a machine key as I understand it is primarily for encryption/decryption which there isn't any.

Anyone have an idea of the cause or can point to somewhere with same issue?

Comment: `List<T>` is not thread-safe.  Don't do that.

Comment: @VladimirArustamian: There is no reason to `await` like that.

Comment: I don't know, but may be WriteApiLogAsync(requests).ConfigureAwait(false) will help. Also, you will need to add ConfigureAwait(false) to all async methods calls. Probably will not change anything, but try anyway.

Comment: SLaks you say it is no thread-safe. Do you know how to make it so it is thread safe and keeps on stacking if the file is locked? I don't want to lose log requests.

Comment: You should not use Task.Run in asp.net at all because the runtime knows nothing about the thread and will have no qualms recycling if it needs to. It works flawlessly until it doesn't. A better way is to distribute that operation with something like a queue.

Comment: Thanks everyone 4 ur comments. Looks like I need to go back and revisit how thinga r done